# Change Meteor.js Accounts Database?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am building an app using Meteor.js, which has a pretty cool "accounts" package that puts user info into a Mongo collection called "users". In my app, I want to have two different types of users - A and B. How can I change the accounts package to bind to different mongo collections?

Comment: Does an extra field on the user document not suffice? E.g. just add `type: A` to the document?

Comment: Oskar is correct. You want to type users via keys in the users collection. Towards multiple user collections lies madness.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. In that case, my problem is that when I press "create a new user", the only fields that pop up are Username, Email, Password. How can I add more fields (name, address, etc).

Comment: There is a `profile` field which can be used to hold custom data.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an user, insert a property as the user's type.

```
Accounts.createUser({
    username: 'name',
    email: 'mail',
    password: 'pwd',
    profile: { type: 'typeA' }
});
```

With that being created, tell which type the user is if the user has signed in.

```
var userType = Meteor.user().profile.type;
```

**Notice**

When dealing with profile, be cautious for security as pointed out in the [document](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users)

> profile: an Object which the user can create and update with any data. Do not store anything on profile that you wouldn't want the user to edit unless you have a deny rule on the Meteor.users collection.

Comment: It should be noted that the `profile` field can always be changed by the client.

Comment: I second @Oskar. Without appropriate allow/deny rules in place, this is very insecure. Just imagine if typeA was an administrator. I stay away from profile altogether.

Comment: As pointed in the above comments, notices could have been given as well to avoid problems, and they are added.